# VB.net - DevExpress WindowsUIButtonPanel

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have been trying to define click event for 6 buttons I have created in the WINDOWSUIBUTTONPANEL but I am unable to do so.
I have tried:

```
    Private Sub WindowsUIButtonPanel1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WindowsUIButtonPanel1.ButtonClick
**THINGS TO DO**
    End Sub
```

But all the buttons do the same
I tried to add:

```
For Each WindowsUIButtonPanel1.Buttons.OfType(1)

        Next
```

But again it does not work
Can someone help me on this please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the following approach:

```
Private Sub WindowsUIButtonPanel1_ButtonClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.ButtonEventArgs) Handles WindowsUIButtonPanel1.ButtonClick
    If e.Button Is WindowsUIButtonPanel1.Buttons(0) Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Button 0")
        ' do something
    End If
    If e.Button Is WindowsUIButtonPanel1.Buttons(1) Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Button 1")
        ' do something
    End If
End Sub
```